# Adjective for "makes other people jealous"

Tags: single-word-requests

How can you succinctly say that something is likely to draw the jealousy of others?

> That would be ____

Especially if it's slightly negative too, attracting not only jealousy but also hate or dislike because of how jealous they are

Comment: What is “something”? Behavior, comment, a suggestion or what

Comment: Your example sentence isn't very useful, as pretty much any adjective could work in that blank.

Comment: Is there any reason you can’t say *That would provoke jealousy*? (Also, *jealous* already contains the sense of *hostile* and *resentful*.)

Comment: Would **enviable** be too pedestrian?

Comment: There are nuances and it would depend on what are you wanting to describe: possessions, girlfriends, jobs, status, events, abstract qualities...? People argue a lot about the precise difference between envy and jealousy, with usage guides not necessarily matching everyday usage.

Comment: That would likely spark jealousy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's **invidiogenic**, which is not in the dictionaries and, according to Google, has only been used by one writer; Elisabeth Ladenson, *[Invidia's Snake](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40003527)*,
Women's Studies Quarterly, Vol. 34, No. 3/4, Envy (Fall - Winter, 2006):

> all that much more invidiogenic than other professions

Ladenson has presumably coined "invidiogenic" directly from Latin *[invidia](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/invidia)*, one of the [Seven Deadly Sins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_deadly_sins) as listed by Aquinas, which may be translated as "Envy" or "Jealousy" - "spite and resentment at seeing the success of another", which fits the OP's requirement.

For everyday writing, however, we only have **jealousy-inducing**:

[E. G. Brainard Jr, Psychological Reports, 1996](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/9009788/)

> Use and approval of jealousy-inducing behaviors were good predictors of high need for interpersonal control and the use of psychological aggression.

[The Ketchum Blog, 2011](https://www.ketchum.com/three-features-of-jealousy-inducing-campaigns/)

> Three Features of Jealousy-Inducing Campaigns

[Free Birds Magazine, 2020](https://freebirdsmagazine.com/funforlouis-is-truly-living-the-jealousy-inducing-adventurous-life/)

> FunForLouis is truly living the (jealousy-inducing) adventurous life!

[The Week, 2023](https://theweek.com/feature/1026071/homes-with-spectacular-pools)

> 6 jealousy-inducing homes with spectacular pools

Comment: There is _invidious_ which is in dictionaries.

Comment: But *invidious* (and by extension, *invidiogenic*) means "likely to incur resentment or ill-will," not "likely to engender jealousy." It means people are likely to object, not covet.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Ladenson has presumably coined *invidiogenic* directly from Latin *invidia* (envy), the term used by Aquinas for the Deadly Sin, rather than via English *invidious*.

Comment: @Tevildo I think you should put that in your answer (contrasting with the usual meaning of *invidious*) to explain how *invidiogenic* is actually relevant ― and, indeed, supplies a meaning which English probably doesn't otherwise have.

Comment: No; _invidiogenic_ doesn't have enough enough currency (1 hit on Google) to be a valid suggestion on ELU, which confines itself to standard usages.

Comment: One of the senses of _invidious_ fits. _OED_ definition of this sense: "Of a thing: Fitted to excite ill feeling or envy against the possessor." It is connected to its Latin etymon  _invidiōsus_, from _invidia_ 'envy'.

Answer (score 1):

### Enviable

Causing envy in others. Note that envy does not have quite the same negative connotations as jealous.

### Covetable

To covert is to desire to possess as in “Thou should not covert thy neighbour’s ass” Exodus 20:17. Like many biblical words it has a slightly archaic air but it does have the same underhanded feel of jealousy.